# Remove Site Stats and Elementor widgets from wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to remove the following two widgets from the dashboard for specific users.
1. Site Stats
2. Elementor Overview

I've unsuccessfully searched to get the widget IDs. Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_widgets' );
function remove_widgets($query) {  
     if(!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {

        /* these don't seem to be working */
        remove_meta_box( 'e-dashboard-overview', 'dashboard', 'normal');
        unregister_widget('WP_Statistics');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the action to 'wp_dashboard_setup' (rather than 'admin_init').

The code for the Elementor dashboard is correct - I can't answer to site stats.